# Summation of the reciprocals of natural numbers which does not have 0 as a digit.

Tags: rational-numbers

What is the summation of reciprocals according to multiplication of natural numbers which does not have 0 as a digit?
$$
S = \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}..+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}+...+\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{111}...
$$
I try to think first all zeros were there
$$\sum \frac{1}{i}$$ it is ln(X) so it goes to infinity
I try to delete multiples of 10
$$\sum \frac{1}{i}-\sum \frac{1}{10*i}$$
still infinity
by this type of elimination and I sandwiched it between two series. a number between  21.88 and 25.433 can be answer, and ı was expecting a solution closer to lower limit

the series do not diverge, ı can find a series bounding above that their sum is convergent. sum_(ı=0 to infty) 9(9/10)^i  is an upper bound. there is 9 element less than 1 in 1/1+1/2.+1/9, there 9^2 element less than 1/10in 1/11+1/11...1/99, and there is 9^3 elements less than 1/100 in 1/111+1/112...+1/999, so continues.
by this logic (sum 1/n, n=1,9)+(sum (sum 1/(kx10+n),n=1,9),k=1,9)(sum (9/10)^i,i=0,infty) is also an upper bound which add up to 23.4841
(sum 1/n, n=1,9)+(sum (sum 1/(kx10+n),n=2,10),k=1,9)(sum (9/10)^i,i=0,infty) is a lower bound which add up to 22.72

ı will try to write a more elaborate try later but, I didn't want my question to be deleted

Comment: Interesting question but unfortunately it will likely get closed since you did not show any effort you made to solve it.

Comment: thaks for warning, then ı will  try to write my attempt then post the question again

Comment: You should write your attempt in this present version. rather than post another.

Comment: Maybe not helpful to answering the question, but you might find the [Kempner Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series) interesting if you haven't already seen it, which is the sum of the reciprocals of all natural numbers not containing a 9 digit.

Comment: thanks I will have a look

Comment: The series should still divergse , but I do not see yet an easy proof for that.

Comment: the series do not diverge, ı can find a series bounding above that their sum is convergent. sum_(ı=0 to infty) 9(9/10)^i  is an upper bound. there is 9 element less than 1, there 9^2 element less than 1/10, and there is 9^3 elements less than 1/100, so continues.

Comment: What counts as a 0 in the number? $1/2=0.50000...$ for example, and $1/12=0.833333$, If those must not be included, then the sum is $1/1+1/3+1/6+1/7+1/9$

Comment: I found [a 1979 paper by Robert Baillie](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.4410.pdf) that gives an algorithm to compute this sum (actuall the linked paper appears to be a 2023 update of the 1979 paper). It seems that there is no known explicit formula.

Comment: thanks ı make the computation the answer 23.1 with error margin of 0.01